# Remove node element without removing innerHTML

Tags: javascript, arrays, removechild

I'm refactoring a vanilla JS Wheel of Fortune/Hangman game and I'm trying to figure out how to remove the previous node elements displayed in the underscores representing the letters in the word the user is trying to guess. If the user picks a word that's 5-6 letters, that usually fine because the next random word is probably more than 5-6 letters so it will overwrite the shorter array of underscores. My problem is, a word like "JAVASCRIPT", causes problems. If the user gets "ARRAYS", the "RIPT" from the previous "JAVASCRIPT" remains on the page. I tried several things like window.location.reload(), but I don't want to reload the page each time the user guesses the word correctly since I want to add a point-based system. I tried wordDisplay.remove() but no luck. Lastly, I tried

```
wordDisplay.childNodes.forEach(child => {
    wordDisplay.removeChild(child);
 });
```

but this doesn't allow the underscores to show once the play button is hit. It also doesn't completely solve the problem of resetting the childNodes in wordDisplay. Any ideas how I can fix this problem?

```js
let guessesLeft,
    letterClicked,
    wordChoice,
    remainingLetters,
    answerList = [],
    wordArray = ["JAVASCRIPT", "ARRAYS", "FUNCTIONS", "HOISTING", "RECURSION", "EVENTS", "KEYUP", "TERNARY"],
    hint = document.querySelector(".hint"),
    letterGuessed = document.querySelector("#your-guess"),
    numbers = document.querySelector("#numbers"),
    guesses = document.querySelector("#guesses"),
    wordDisplay = document.querySelector("#words"),
    letterCount = document.querySelector(".letters"),
    newGame = document.querySelector("#play"),
    letterBoxes = document.querySelector("#alphabet"),
    titleHeader = document.querySelector(".welcome"),
    pointTotal = document.querySelector("#pointTotal");

function playGame() {

    guessesLeft = 6;
    guesses.innerHTML = `You have ${guessesLeft} guesses left`;
    // Pick a random word.
    wordChoice = wordArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordArray.length)];

    for (var i = 0; i < wordChoice.length; i++) {
        answerList[i] = "_";
    }
    // Display underscores on page representing each letter in the random word
    wordDisplay.innerHTML = answerList.join('');

    let hintObject = {
        JAVASCRIPT: "The language of the web",
        ARRAYS: "Similar to objects",
        FUNCTIONS: "Stores instructions",
        HOISTING: "Moving declarations to the top",
        RECURSION: "Calling functions inside of functions",
        EVENTS: "This happens to HTML elements; like a concert",
        KEYUP: "Not 'keydown', but...",
        TERNARY: "Type of operator"
    }

    hint.innerHTML = `Clue: ${hintObject[wordChoice]}`;

    // Display number of letters in the random word on the page
    remainingLetters = wordChoice.length;
    letterCount.innerHTML = `The word is ${remainingLetters} letters long`;

    // wordDisplay.childNodes.forEach(child => {
    //     wordDisplay.removeChild(child);
    // });
}

// Register the player’s guess.
function buttonPress(e) {
    letterClicked = e.target.textContent;
    letterGuessed.innerHTML = `You guessed the letter ${letterClicked}`;
    matchWord(letterClicked);
}

// Pass the letter event from buttonPress into the randomWord function
function matchWord(letter) {
    pointTotal = 0;
    if (remainingLetters > 0) {
        let foundMatch = false;

        for (var i = 0; i < wordChoice.length; i++) {
            if (wordChoice[i] === letter) {
                foundMatch = true;
                answerList[i] = letter;
                wordDisplay.innerHTML = answerList.join(' ');
                remainingLetters--;
            }
        }

        if (!foundMatch) {
            guessesLeft--;
            guesses.innerHTML = (`You have ${guessesLeft} guesses left`);
        }

        if (guessesLeft === 0) {
            hint.innerHTML = "Sorry, you're out of guesses!";
            setTimeout(function () {
                hint.innerHTML = "If you'd like to play again, click the spin button.";
                letterCount.innerHTML = "You lost :(";
            }, 3000);
        }

        if (remainingLetters === 0) {
            hint.innerHTML = "Great job! You guessed it!";
            pointTotal++;
            setTimeout(function () {
                playGame();
            }, 3000);
        }
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    background: linear-gradient(200deg, #025302, #027740, #05b965, #07e07b, #05532f);
    background-size: contain;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgb(27, 22, 22);
}

#container {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px;
}

#roundsWon {
    margin-left: 15%;
    font-size: 45px;
}

.welcome {
    font-size: 80px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.letters, .lives {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.hint {
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}

#words {
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 20px;
}

#alphabet {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 990px;
}

#letterChoices {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 2em;
    height: 10%;
    font-size: 2em;
    border: 2px solid white;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px black;
}

#play {
    float: left;
    margin: 20px auto;
    font-size: 60px;
}

#your-guess {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5%;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #bada55;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <title>Wheel of Fortune</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="Title">
                <h1 class="welcome">Welcome to Wheel of Fortune!</h1>
            </div>
                <div id="alphabet" onclick="buttonPress(event)">
                    <a id="letterChoices" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">A</a>
                    <a id="letterChoices" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">B</a>
                    <a id="letterChoices" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">C</a>
                    <a id="letterChoices" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">D</a>
                    <a id="letterChoices" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">E</a>
                    <a id="letterChoices" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">F</a>
                    <a id="letterChoices" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">G</a>
                    <a id="letterChoices" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">H</a>
                    <a id="letterChoices" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">I</a>
                    <a id="letterChoices" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">J</a>
                    <a id="letterChoices" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">K</a>
                    <a id="letterChoices" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">L</a>
                    <a id="letterChoices" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">M</a>
                </br>
                    <a id="letterChoices" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">N</a>
                    <a id="letterChoices" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">O</a>
                    <a id="letterChoices" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">P</a>
                    <a id="letterChoices" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">Q</a>
                    <a id="letterChoices" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">R</a>
                    <a id="letterChoices" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">S</a>
                    <a id="letterChoices" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">T</a>
                    <a id="letterChoices" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">U</a>
                    <a id="letterChoices" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">V</a>
                    <a id="letterChoices" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">W</a>
                    <a id="letterChoices" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">X</a>
                    <a id="letterChoices" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">Y</a>
                    <a id="letterChoices" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">Z</a>
                </div>
                <div id="container">
                    <div id="header">
                        <p class="hint">Hint will display once you spin</p>
                        <!-- The letters will be tied to the number of letters in the random array -->
                        <p class="letters">The word is <span id="numbers">_</span> letters long</p>
                        <!-- The user will be given a number of choices and with each wrong choice, they lose a turn -->
                        <p class="lives"><span id="guesses">You have _ guesses remaining</span></p>
                        <p id="words"></p>
                    </br>
                        <a id="play" onclick="playGame()" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">Spin</a>
                        <span id="roundsWon">Rounds won:<span id="pointTotal"></span></span>
                        <span id="your-guess">Letter guessed</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
        
            <script src="main.js"></script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Fiddle seems to be broken, `Uncaught ReferenceError: playGame is not defined`, the button does not do anything. If you would, please post all the code relevant to the question *in the question itself* - don't hide it behind a link. You shouldn't tell potential helpers who would otherwise love to help that they have to navigate offsite just to have an idea of what you're working with. If the link breaks, the question could be rendered useless to future readers. Please edit your code into the question in a [MCVE], or the question might get closed, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset your values after every

```
setTimeout(function () {
        answerList = [];
        letterClicked = '';
        playGame();
}, 3000);
```

As currently your array keeps the letters and you overwrite only some of them and also you keep the last clicked letter.

Answer (score 2):

The **answerList** is declared before. So when random word like 'javascript' is stored in the answerList as '__________' and the length of array **answerList** becomes 10. When a new word like 'arrays' is stored in the answerList as '______' the length of the new wordChoice is less the last one which is 6 so remaining 4 words do not change and this is the reason why **ript** is not removed.

Solution:
add this line

```
answerList = [];
```

before

```
for (var i = 0; i < wordChoice.length; i++) {
    answerList[i] = "_";
}
```

this will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

## Clearing Procedure

The following was added to `playGame()` function:

> ```
> function playGame() {
>   /* Clearing Procedure */
>    wordDisplay.innerHTML = " ";
>    remainingLetters = 0;
>    answerList.length = 0;
>    ...
> ```

There are some superficial changes as well which are purely optional. One thing to remember is that `#ids` must be unique, there were 26 instances of `#letterChoices`.

---

### Demo

```js
let guessesLeft,
  letterClicked,
  wordChoice,
  remainingLetters,
  answerList = [],
  wordArray = ["JAVASCRIPT", "ARRAYS", "FUNCTIONS", "HOISTING", "RECURSION", "EVENTS", "KEYUP", "TERNARY"],
  hint = document.querySelector("#hint"),
  letterGuessed = document.querySelector("#guess"),
  letterCount = document.querySelector("#letters"),
  guesses = document.querySelector("#guesses"),
  wordDisplay = document.querySelector("#words"),
  newGame = document.querySelector("#play"),
  letterBoxes = document.querySelector(".alphabet"),
  titleHeader = document.querySelector("h1"),
  pointTotal = document.querySelector("#pointTotal");

function playGame() {

  /* Clearing Procedure */
  wordDisplay.innerHTML = " ";
  remainingLetters = 0;
  answerList.length = 0;

  guessesLeft = 6;
  guesses.innerHTML = guessesLeft;
  // Pick a random word.
  wordChoice = wordArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordArray.length)];

  for (var i = 0; i < wordChoice.length; i++) {
    answerList[i] = "_";
  }
  // Display underscores on page representing each letter in the random word
  wordDisplay.innerHTML = answerList.join('');

  let hintObject = {
    JAVASCRIPT: "The language of the web",
    ARRAYS: "Similar to objects",
    FUNCTIONS: "Stores instructions",
    HOISTING: "Moving declarations to the top",
    RECURSION: "Calling functions inside of functions",
    EVENTS: "This happens to HTML elements; like a concert",
    KEYUP: "Not 'keydown', but...",
    TERNARY: "Type of operator"
  }

  hint.innerHTML = `Clue: ${hintObject[wordChoice]}`;

  // Display number of letters in the random word on the page
  remainingLetters = wordChoice.length;
  letterCount.innerHTML = remainingLetters;
}

// Register the player’s guess.
function buttonPress(e) {
  letterClicked = e.target.textContent;
  letterGuessed.innerHTML = letterClicked;
  matchWord(letterClicked);
}

// Pass the letter event from buttonPress into the randomWord function
function matchWord(letter) {
  pointTotal = 0;
  if (remainingLetters > 0) {
    let foundMatch = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < wordChoice.length; i++) {
      if (wordChoice[i] === letter) {
        foundMatch = true;
        answerList[i] = letter;
        wordDisplay.innerHTML = answerList.join(' ');
        remainingLetters--;
      }
    }

    if (!foundMatch) {
      guessesLeft--;
      guesses.innerHTML = guessesLeft;
    }

    if (guessesLeft === 0) {
      hint.innerHTML = "Sorry, you're out of guesses!";
      setTimeout(function() {
        hint.innerHTML += "If you'd like to play again, click the spin button.";
        letterCount.innerHTML = "You lost :(";
      }, 3000);
    }

    if (remainingLetters === 0) {
      hint.innerHTML = "Great job! You guessed it!";
      pointTotal++;
      setTimeout(function() {
        playGame();
      }, 3000);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(200deg, #025302, #027740, #05b965, #07e07b, #05532f);
  background-size: contain;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgb(27, 22, 22);
}

.container {
  margin: 20px;
}

[for=pointTotal] {
  margin-left: 15%;
  font-size: 45px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 80px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

label {
  margin: 5px;
}

label,
output {
  display: block;
}

label output {
  display: inline-block;
}

[for=letters],
[for=guesses] {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

#hint {
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}

#words {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 20px;
}

.alphabet {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.letter {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 2em;
  height: 10%;
  font-size: 2em;
  border: 2px solid white;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px black;
}

#play {
  float: left;
  margin: 20px auto;
  font-size: 60px;
}

[for=guess] {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5%;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #bada55;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Wheel of Fortune</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Welcome to Wheel of Fortune!</h1>

  <section class="alphabet" onclick="buttonPress(event)">
    <a class="letter waves-effect waves-light btn-large">A</a>
    <a class="letter waves-effect waves-light btn-large">B</a>
    <a class="letter waves-effect waves-light btn-large">C</a>
    <a class="letter waves-effect waves-light btn-large">D</a>
    <a class="letter waves-effect waves-light btn-large">E</a>
    <a class="letter waves-effect waves-light btn-large">F</a>
    <a class="letter waves-effect waves-light btn-large">G</a>
    <a class="letter waves-effect waves-light btn-large">H</a>
    <a class="letter waves-effect waves-light btn-large">I</a>
    <a class="letter waves-effect waves-light btn-large">J</a>
    <a class="letter waves-effect waves-light btn-large">K</a>
    <a class="letter waves-effect waves-light btn-large">L</a>
    <a class="letter waves-effect waves-light btn-large">M</a>
    <a class="letter waves-effect waves-light btn-large">N</a>
    <a class="letter waves-effect waves-light btn-large">O</a>
    <a class="letter waves-effect waves-light btn-large">P</a>
    <a class="letter waves-effect waves-light btn-large">Q</a>
    <a class="letter waves-effect waves-light btn-large">R</a>
    <a class="letter waves-effect waves-light btn-large">S</a>
    <a class="letter waves-effect waves-light btn-large">T</a>
    <a class="letter waves-effect waves-light btn-large">U</a>
    <a class="letter waves-effect waves-light btn-large">V</a>
    <a class="letter waves-effect waves-light btn-large">W</a>
    <a class="letter waves-effect waves-light btn-large">X</a>
    <a class="letter waves-effect waves-light btn-large">Y</a>
    <a class="letter waves-effect waves-light btn-large">Z</a>
  </section>
  <section class="container">
    <header>
      <output id="hint">Hint will display once you spin</output>
      <!-- The letters will be tied to the number of letters in the random array -->
      <label for="letters">The word is <output id="letters">_</output> letters long</label>
      <!-- The user will be given a number of choices and with each wrong choice, they lose a turn -->
      <label for='guesses'>You have <output id="guesses">_</output> guesses remaining</label>
      <output id="words"></output>
      <br>
      <a id="play" onclick="playGame()" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">Spin</a>
      <label for="pointTotal">Rounds won:<output id="pointTotal"></output></label>
      <label for="guess">Letter guessed <output id='guess'>_</output></label>
    </header>

  </section>
</body>

</html>
```